# Множественные переменные в SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Мне нужно сделать выборку с БД но я не знаю количество параметров по которым ищу. Пример запроса

```
SELECT Ingredients.name FROM Ingredients WHERE Ingredients._id IN (?);
```

Там где знак вопроса - там может бить несколько параметров.
Пример

```
SELECT Ingredients.name FROM Ingredients WHERE Ingredients._id IN ('1' , '4');
```

Делаю запросы в DB Browser for SQLite - все работает. Делаю на яве ,под Андроид, вот такой запрос

```
cursor c2 = myDbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT Ingredients.name " +
                "FROM Ingredients" +
                "WHERE Ingredients._id IN(?);", new String[]{"'1' , '2'"});
```

не работает.

Пробовал по всякому

```
new String[]{"'1 , 2'"} 
    и new String[]{"1 , 2"}
```

и как только не извращался - не работает. Помогите

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343946/sqlite-query-for-multiple-values-in-one-columm

Это не помогла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так:

```
String[] inParams = { "1", "2" };
String query = "SELECT Ingredients.name FROM Ingredients" + " WHERE Ingredients._id IN (" + makeParams(inParams.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.rawQuery(query, inParams);
```

Реализуйте метод makeParams:

```
private String makeParams(int length) {
    if (length < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Нет условий для поиска");
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length * 2 - 1);
        sb.append("?");
        for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            sb.append(",?");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Но разве нету более элегантного способа? Этот выглядит не коректно.